# How to overlay text on image when working with cv::Mat type

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision

I am using opencv 2.1. In my code I have a few images stored as Mat objects initialized like this:

```
Mat img1 = imread("img/stuff.pgm", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
```

I can display them properly using imshow() after my matrix operations are done. Now I want to add some text on the image to describe what has happened. Looking at the documentation it seems like `cvPutText()` would be the function I need. But when I try something like this:

`cvPutText(result, "Differencing the two images.", cvPoint(30,30), &font, GREEN);`

I get the following compile error:
`error: cannot convert ‘cv::Mat’ to ‘CvArr*’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘void cvPutText(CvArr*, const char*, CvPoint, const CvFont*, CvScalar)’`

What do I need to do to be able to add some text when displaying this image?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

I was looking at the wrong place. I found the answer in the newer [OpenCV documentation for cpp](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/drawing_functions.html#puttext). There is a new function called putText() that accepts cv::Mat objects. So I tried this line and it works:

```
putText(result, "Differencing the two images.", cvPoint(30,30), 
    FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX_SMALL, 0.8, cvScalar(200,200,250), 1, CV_AA);
```

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Unfortunately, this only works for ASCII characters… If someone has a better solution, I'll take it!

Comment: @Eliyahu-Shmuel it's 'putText' not 'PutText'.  I use it like so `cv::putText`

Comment: It's not print me anything on my image. my code: Mat fre = imread("1.jpg", 0);
 putText(fre, "Differencing the two images.", cvPoint(30, 30),
  FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX_SMALL, 0.8, cvScalar(200, 200, 250), 1, CV_AA);

Answer (score 27):

For C++ basic use in OpenCV 3 or greater:

```
cv::putText(yourImageMat, 
            "Text to add",
            cv::Point(5,5), // Coordinates (Bottom-left corner of the text string in the image)
            cv::FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX_SMALL, // Font
            1.0, // Scale. 2.0 = 2x bigger
            cv::Scalar(255,255,255), // BGR Color
            1, // Line Thickness (Optional)
            cv:: LINE_AA); // Anti-alias (Optional, see version note)
```

See [putText()](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d6/d6e/group__imgproc__draw.html#ga5126f47f883d730f633d74f07456c576) in OpenCV 4 docs, or old [2.x docs](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/drawing_functions.html#void%20putText(Mat&%20img,%20const%20string&%20text,%20Point%20org,%20int%20fontFace,%20double%20fontScale,%20Scalar%20color,%20int%20thickness,%20int%20lineType,%20bool%20bottomLeftOrigin)) .

Note: Versions before OpenCV 2.x use `CV_AA` instead of `LINE_AA`

Comment: For the future readers: Note that in `cv::putText`, coordinates mentioned through `cv::Point` corresponds to the ***Bottom-left** corner of the text string in the image*

Answer (score 8):

```
putText(result, "Differencing the two images.", cvPoint(30,30), 
    FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX_SMALL, 0.8, cvScalar(200,200,250), 1, CV_AA);
```

In the above line "result" should be a cvArr* or an IplImage*. but from the code provided here, I guess you are passing a cv::Mat object.
So, you either need to convert it using cvarrToMat() or pass &result instead of result.

Hope it helps

Comment: Good catch, I didn't known about this conversion - I was using it with a Mat object without success.

Answer (score 2):

You can also do the following to print text and variables.

```
    std::ostringstream str;
    str << "Here is some text:" << myVariable;
    cv::putText(image, cv::Point(10,10), str.str(), CV_FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, CV_RGB(0,0,250));
```

Comment: This does not appear to work. why are there `i`s in your scalar? why is `<< "Here..."` outside the parenthesis? I could not get this example to compile.

Comment: I know what the operator is. Your answer does not compile as is and you left no explanation about what's going on. I was hoping you'd edit your answer to a MWE that actually compiles.

Comment: I updated the answer. Thanks for the correction.  The `<<` overloading needs another library that's not part of openCV distribution by default.

Answer (score 2):

One nasty detail that I saw into my test code: pay attention into the import stament - it is not displayed into most examples and it needs to be the right import.

My test code used only the putText sample above and I did included the imgproc.h just as I did into some of my oldcode. The code compiled and linked fine however I was facing one weirdy behaviour with the putText (some garbage into my image).

It was a PITA until I figured out that the import was messing up with my social life ...

imageText.cpp

```
#include "Imaging/imageText.h"
#include "Commons/xLog.h"
#include "opencv2/imgproc.hpp" // << Seems to work right?
using namespace cv;

namespace imaging
{
   inline Mat image2mat( SmartImage image ) NOEXCEPTION
   {
      //TODO: hard coded to work only with CV_8UC3, see the other cases ...
      Mat mat(
         Size( image->WIDTH, image->HEIGHT ),
         CV_8UC3,
         image->buffer,
         Mat::AUTO_STEP
      );

      return mat;
   }

   inline void _writeText_( SmartImage image, const string TEXT )
   {
      Mat mat( image2mat( image ) );

      string text = "Funny text inside the box";
      int fontFace = FONT_HERSHEY_SCRIPT_SIMPLEX;
      double fontScale = 2;
      int thickness = 3;  
      Point textOrg( 10, 130 );
      putText( mat, text, textOrg, fontFace, fontScale, Scalar::all( 255 ), thickness, 8 );
   }

   const bool writeText( SmartImage image, const string text )  NOEXCEPTION
   {
      try
      {
         _writeText_( image, text );
         return true;
      }
      catch( cv::Exception& e )
      {
         LOG_ERROR( "writeText OpenCV ERROR: " << e.what() << "!" );
      }
      catch( ... )
      {
         LOG_ERROR( "writeText ERROR!" );
      }
      return false;
   }
}
```

Then I just changed the imgproc import above to

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp> // << It does includes ALL opencv stuff
```

My 5 cents.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using OpenCV 3.x or 4.0, you have to replace `CV_AA` by `LINE_AA`. So, the complete call would be:

```cpp
cv::putText(yourImageMat, 
            "Text to add",
            cv::Point(5,5), // Coordinates
            cv::FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX_SMALL, // Font
            1.0, // Scale. 2.0 = 2x bigger
            cv::Scalar(255,255,255), // BGR Color
            1, // Line Thickness (Optional)
            cv::LINE_AA); // Anti-alias (Optional)
```

This was posted in [this forum](http://bugsinmycodes.blogspot.com/2016/11/opencv3-no-attribute-name-cvaa.html).

Answer (score -1):

putText(img1, "TextString123", cvPoint(50,200), FONT_HERSHEY_SCRIPT_SIMPLEX, 2.5, cvScalar(255,0,0,255), 3, CV_AA);

You can find more information here: http://docs.opencv.org/2.4.9/modules/core/doc/drawing_functions.html

The main diference between this answer and the answers from above is the value of the 7-th parameter, the thickness level. With thickness==1 this function have not worked for me.

Comment: This question is already answered satisfactory, so you really need a bit of explanation to justify what's different/better about your answer. It also isn't clear from your answer what `matImg1` is (it doesn't appear in the question).

Comment: This uses the C interface of openCV (vs c++) which is really old.